# Curious Response of JS Array Reduce

Tags: javascript

Been using JS reduce on arrays and I stumbled on this weird undefined response when I used it on an object.

Here is the input:

```
var desks = [
  { type: "sitting" },
  { type: "standing" },
  { type: "sitting" },
  { type: "sitting" },
  { type: "standing" },
];
```

and here is the function that am trying to run this input on:

```
const deskCount = (desks) => {
  desks.reduce(
    (count, thisdesk) => {
      if (thisdesk.type == "sitting") count.sitting = count.sitting + 1;
      if (thisdesk.type == "standing") count.standing = count.standing + 1;
      console.log(count); //this line is logging correctly but function returns undefined
      return count;
    },
    { sitting: 0, standing: 0 }
  );
};
```

Running it using Node 12.18.0 and wrapped with babel.

Comment: `deskCount` function does not return anything, remove curly braces or add `return` before `desks.reduce(..`

Comment: Thanks Travis J for the answer.  Sticking with having a return statement though as suggested by @Yevgen for consistency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you have used a multi-line arrow function without returning a value. The inner `reduce` runs fine, however, the wrapping code does not return anything when it is inside of `{}`.

Either use return for the wrapping `{}`, or omit the `{}`. I think omitting is best.

```
const deskCount = (desks) =>
  desks.reduce(
    (count, thisdesk) => {
      if (thisdesk.type == "sitting") count.sitting = count.sitting + 1;
      if (thisdesk.type == "standing") count.standing = count.standing + 1;
      console.log(count); //this line is logging correctly but function returns undefined
      return count;
    },
    { sitting: 0, standing: 0 }
  );
```